# connection refused by server error when codenameone project is copied to another machine

Tags: intellij-idea, google-api, codenameone

I have a very strange problem:

- I have created a project in Intellij using the Codename One plugin.
- In this project I access a Google Sheet using Oauth2 authentication
  following these directions from the Codename One site.
  https://www.codenameone.com/google-login.html
- My code to do this works fine on my computer (Windows 10).
- If I copy that code to another computer (Windows 10 or OS X) and try to access the Google Sheet, I get a "Connection refused by server" error.
- Specifically, I get the error after I click on the "Allow" button in
  the Google Login dialog box.
- I have tried this on several computers.
- I receive the error no matter what network/ISP I am using when I try to access the Google Sheet.

The stack trace relating to the error looks like this:

```
java.lang.Throwable: Connection refused by server
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.describeError(WebEngine.java:1461)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1400)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$1200(WebEngine.java:1278)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1265)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2443)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2287)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.twkDidFail(Native Method)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.notifyDidFail(URLLoader.java:883)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.lambda$didFail$102(URLLoader.java:866)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The code that is being executed when the error is generated is:

```
    public void oauth2GoogleLogin()
    {

    String clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    String redirectURI = "http://localhost:8080";
    String clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    Login gc = GoogleConnect.getInstance();
    gc.setClientId(clientId);
    gc.setRedirectURI(redirectURI);
    gc.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    gc.setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets");
    gc.setCallback(new LoginCallback() { 
        @Override
        public void loginFailed(String errorMessage) {
            super.loginFailed(errorMessage);
        }
        @Override
        public void loginSuccessful() {
            super.loginSuccessful();
            System.out.println("Logged in.");
            token = gc.getAccessToken().getToken();
            //saveData();
        }
    });

    if(!gc.isUserLoggedIn()){
        gc.doLogin();
    }else{
        ....some code to do stuff...
    }
}
```

As I have said, this code works fine on the computer where I wrote it, but if I transfer the Intellij/Codename One project to another computer, it no longer works.

It seems to me that the problem is probably in the callback, and that the server that is refusing the connection is probably my own computer being accessed via the http://localhost:8080. But I'm not sure. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: That's internal to the browser component and doesn't reach our code. How is the JDK/FX environment different between the machines?

Comment: Thanks for your help Shai. The jdk for the machine that is able to access a Google Sheet is jdk1.8.0_112. The jdk for the machine that is not able to access a Google Sheet is jdk1.8.0_20. The first machine is running Windows 10. The second machine is running Sierra.

Comment: Sorry to be so dense, but when you say "That's internal to the browser component..." What is the "that" you are referencing? Do you mean the stack trace?

Comment: Yes, I'm referencing the stack trace. The exception is entirely in JavaFX and has no line mentioning our code (or yours). Try updating the JDK and make sure both machines have the latest version of the Codename One libraries `Codename One Settings -> Basics -> Update Client Libs`

Comment: OK. I upgraded a Mac running El Capitan and a PC running Windows 10 to the latest Java jdk. And I upgraded the project on each computer to the latest Client Libs. On both machines the Google Login Dialog starts (spinning arrows) but then stops without the dialog box appearing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does it fail on both now? Is it the same stack trace?

Comment: Sorry my earlier comment wasn't clear. I have a Windows 10 PC (let's call it the dev computer) that the project was created on that works (that is to say that it allows me to successfully do an oauth2 login to a Google Sheet). I have a second Windows 10 PC and an El Capitan Mac (let's call these the new computers). All three computers are updated to the 1.8 jdk. I copied the project created on the dev machine to the new machines and was getting the stack trace above. At your suggestion, I updated both the new computers to the most recent Java jdk.

Comment: I also updated the Codename One libraries on the new computers. Now, the new computers no longer throw an error, but I still can't complete an oauth2 login to Google on either of them. The Google Login Dialog appears to start but then stops without any explanation. The actual Google dialog boxes never appear. I have not made any changes to the dev computer, and it still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If both machines no longer work that makes more sense that a regression in newer versions of JavaFX's web browser broke the Google OAuth2 process.

Unfortunately, that's a huge problem. We can't fix JavaFX and if they push out a broken update we are stuck.

A workaround might be to try an older version of the VM e.g. 1.8.67 or something.